# Substract every element in an array and find the largest among them

Tags: c++, arrays, comparison

My problem is that I have an array with birthdays, and I need to find the biggest age difference among every birthday.

I was thinking of substracting every year and storing the differences in an array, and finding the largest difference in that temporary array.

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int t[5] = {1999,2001,1996,1998,1999};
    int temp[10] = {0};
    for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
    {
       for (int j=i+1; j<5; j++)
       {
         if(t[i] > t[j])
         {
            temp[i] = t[i] - t[j];
         }
          else  if (t[i] < t[j])
         {
            temp[i] = t[j] - t[i];
         }
         else 
         {
            temp[i] = 0;
         }
       }
     }

    for (int i=0; i<10;i++)
    cout << temp[i] <<" ";

    return 0;
}
```

When I try this, I don't get every age difference, the program only works for the first element.

I'm having difficulties with this part, I can manage to find the largest element, when I have the right values in the temporary array.

Comment: Why not simply sort the entries?  Then you know which year is furthest away from the year you're checking.  It's either going to be the first element or the last element.

Comment: Now seems like a very good time to [learn how to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie: `std::minmax_element` is enough.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing the computed difference at location `i` of this `temp` array. The value of `i` only updates after the inner `j` loop has completed execution. This results in the values being overwritten. Try something like:

```
 int k = 0;
 for (int i=0; i<5;i++)
 {
      for (int j=i+1; j<5; j++)
      {
           if(t[i] > t[j])
           {
               temp[k] = t[i] - t[j];
           }
           else  if (t[i] < t[j])
           {
               temp[k] = t[j] - t[i];
           }
           else 
           {
               temp[k] = 0;
           }
           k++;
       }
  }
```